# Adding Double Quotes removes \ from the string

Tags: c#

I am trying trying to add double quotes around a string but when ever I do it **removes** the first `\`from the string.

I know I can add double quotes directly inside the string but I want to know **why this method is not working**.

**Code**

```
string SFilename = "\\FilePath";
SFilename = "\"" + SFilename + "\"";
Console.WriteLine(SFilename);
```

**Output**

```
"\FilePath"
```

Comment: Because it treats(`\\`) as an escape sequence. So it prints out a single `\`

Comment: your code is working, ` \\ ` is interpreted simply ` \ `

Comment: Hint: print `SFilename` after the first line... it's not what you think.

Comment: @JonSkeet who can argue with you Sir!. But after the first line it is \\FilePath

Comment: [Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: Try `string SFilename = @"\\FilePath";`.  Using a verbatim string means what you see is what you get (except for double quotes which need to be escaped by doubling them up).

Comment: As an aside, use the methods in the `System.IO.Path` class for manipulating file paths.  You will save yourself a lot of headaches (like this one).

Comment: @ChrisDunaway like this one ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because the you escape on of your `\` in the original string.
You need to write:

```
string SFilename = "\\\\FilePath";
```

or you could simply use this (would result in the same thing):

```
string SFilename = @"\\FilePath";
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add double quotes with code with ought changing the string?

Comment: @Alexander You can use `@` symbol before your string

Comment: when you want to add quotes to the string you need to watch out though when using @, cause you then need to escape them with another quote. so e.g. `string SFileName = @"""\\FilePath""";`

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape sequence. You can either use `\\` to add a single `\` or surround the string with `@` to declare it as verbatim.

```
string SFilename = @"\\FilePath";
SFilename = "\"" + SFilename + "\"";
Console.WriteLine(SFilename);
```

Comment: Note it's already a literal string.  The terminology you are looking for is verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a const string and @:

```
const string quote = @"""";
string SFilename = @"\\FilePath";
SFilename = quote + SFilename + quote;
Console.WriteLine(SFilename);
```